# Which css and js links should I use?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am confused as to why there is a difference in both of these CDN links when used to modify my simple website. What is the difference?

**Method 1**: These links allows my code to resize perfectly as the window goes from widest possible width to minimum width using chrome, IE11, and Firefox. The problem is 2-fold: 1) I lose the `<span class="input-group-addon">$</span>` as a neat looking symbol and instead get a plain ol' dollar sign. 2) I am a beginner, so I don't know if using these seemingly outdated links will make me have to backktrack in the future. [See example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yv6vlKF7DhB1KfLfFCKn?p=preview).

```
<link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="2.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.1" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="2.3.2" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Method 2**: These links have a hiccup when resizing. As you pass mid-width the AddMoney element jumps to the full width of the textarea above it. I want it to resize similar to the above. Fortunately, these links are directly from the current bootstrap page so I assume they are the most recent. [Using the same link above simply paste over the js and css links using the below.](http://plnkr.co/edit/yv6vlKF7DhB1KfLfFCKn?p=preview)

```
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="2.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.1" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="2.3.2" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your first example, you are including Bootstrap 2 and in the second you are including Bootstrap 3. These two versions of Bootstrap are vastly different in the way the HTML needs to be structured as well as what features they offer. I would suggest that you use the latest version of Bootstrap 3, so go take a look [at the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) to figure out how the HTML should be formatted for that version and adjust your code accordingly.